# how to print cross mark (✕) or check mark ✓ in TCL

Tags: tcl

I would like to print either crossmark (**✕**) or right (check) symbol (**✓**) in `TCL` either using echo or puts.

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: have you tried `echo "\u2715"` and `echo "\u2713"`?

Comment: both of these print only "?"   Does it have any dependence on the operating system used ?

Comment: @boppu What about `\texttimes` from `textcomp` package for x mark and `\checkmark` from `amssymb`?

Answer (score 26):

Use their unicode escape sequences:

```
puts \u2713 ;# check mark

puts \u2717 ;# cross mark
```

There are several different cross marks you can use:

```
✗ = \u2717  BALLOT X
✘ = \u2718  HEAVY BALLOT X
❌ = \u274c CROSS MARK
× = \u00D7  MULTIPLICATION SIGN
╳ = \u2573  BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DIAGONAL CROSS
☓ = \u2613  SALTIRE (St. Andrew's Cross)
✕ = \u2715  MULTIPLICATION X
✖ = \u2716  HEAVY MULTIPLICATION X
⨉ = \u2A09  N-ARY TIMES OPERATOR
```

There are also several alternatives for check marks:

```
✓ = \u2713  CHECK MARK
✔ = \u2714  HEAVY CHECK MARK
```

Comment: it prints  "?", does it have any dependency on the OS used?

Comment: @boppu: It depends on what fonts you have installed. Modern terminals should ONLY ever use utf8 capable fonts.

Comment: What terminal are you running the script in? Don't tell me cmd.com!!?

Comment: I am using standard gnome terminal, and I can print them using python code. can  you be more clear, I am new to utf-8 and fonts

Comment: Gnome terminal? It ought to work, but double check what `fconfigure stdout -encoding` reports. It should be `utf-8` but if it isn't then you can get that sort of problem.

Comment: @Daniel:  you are right it is not utf-8: fconfigure stdout -encoding
iso8859-1

Answer (score 1):

In **python**, you can just do this. This should be okay with other programming languages:

```
print("✓")
print("✕")
print("\u274c")
print ("\u2713")
```

Which gives output:

[image: Output]